# Translating PHP to Python : Finding Min and Max time per Identifier

Tags: php, python, timestamp

I'm working on translating some php code to Python. I'm not an expert in either. This may be a lot, but a little bit of would be appreciated.

I'm especially struggling with this chunk of the code. Here, we have an identifer identifer, namely row[0]row[1]row[2]. Row[4] is a timestamp. For each identifier, we want to find the 'start' and 'end' dates -- named as you would think. This is how a colleague wrote the code to do so: I've added the comments as I understand what is happening but not how to translate this to Python.

So far in Python I've been able to create a dictionary of identifier : timestamp, but have not been able to successfully use that to my advantage in this part of the problem.

Questions:
- Am I missing something very obvious and helpful about Python in this instance? 
- Anywhere I can find an easy to understand mapping of PHP to Python rules (if it exists)?

```
fgetcsv($inputhandle);  //read input as csv
while ($row = fgetcsv($inputhandle)) {  //read each line in record
    $date_arr =   date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s",$row[4]); //parse timestamp
$newdate = mktime($date_arr['hour'], 
                    $date_arr['minute'],
                    $date_arr['second'],
                    $date_arr['month'],
                    $date_arr['day'],
                    $date_arr['year']); //store each piece in array form        

$endpoints[$row[0]][$row[1]][$row[2]]['end'] = $newdate; //identify endpoint                    

if(!isset($records[$row[0]][$row[1]][$row[2]])) { 
    $endpoints[$row[0]][$row[1]][$row[2]]['start'] = $newdate; //identify startpoint
}

$records[$row[0]][$row[1]][$row[2]][$newdate]=$row[5]; //row 5 holds values we care about
```

}

For context, here is the process that I'm trying to replicate:

```
identify endpoints of time<br>
starttime<br>
endtime<br>
create 15 minute time vector while : startime < time < endtime<br>
```

---

Here's what I have so far in Python:

```
import sys
import csv
from datetime
import time
import numpy
import itertools

//open file with csv reader
filename = open('ICUdata.csv', 'rb')

d = {} // declare dictionary variable

//read file as csv, parse
spam = csv.reader(filename, delimiter=',')


next(spam) #skip header
for row in spam: // first fill in missing values
if row[1] == '': 
    row[1] = '99999'
if row[2] == '':
    row[2] = '99999'

//need datetime parse
datestring = row[4]
date = time.strptime(datestring, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") // parsed datetime

    //create dictionary of identifiers : realtime
k = id #need this instead of just row[0:3] which creates list
v = row[4]

if k not in d:
    d[k] = [v]
    #this = row[0:3].append(endpoint)
else:
    d[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something that may be of use to you is the `struct_time` in package time that is returned by the `time.strptime(string[, format])`. It is a named tuple.

A little code to demonstrate:

```
import time
fifth_element_of_row = "2000-12-31 23:11:12"
my_time_struct = time.strptime(fifth_element_of_row, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print my_time_struct
```

which produces the output:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2000, tm_mon=12, 
tm_mday=31, tm_hour=23, tm_min=11, tm_sec=12, 
tm_wday=6, tm_yday=366, tm_isdst=-1)
```

from which the individual elements can be recovered via:

```
print my_time_struct.tm_year
```

which outputs

```
2000
```

Edit: I rushed through this when I saw the date bits. Surprisingly, nobody else has answered yet so I'll try to sweeten the pot for you a bit.

I personally would have probably just done file.readline() and re.split() for csv's because I have a tendency to be a DIY'er (or NIH'er, depending on how you want to color that one...)

Through a bit of research though, I've just learned that python specifically has a csv module for handling such situations. It's been around since 2.3 and is surely more robust than doing it yourself. Go figure.

Sources for your perusal:

[Python time module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html)

[Python csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Comment: Thank you! I realized I should add the code I've been using but it's a good relief to know I've been doing things right so far.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe thirdparty dateutil module (you will need to install it first, see http://labix.org/python-dateutil ) could be helpful:

```
import dateutil.parser
# ...
endpoints[someindex] = dateutil.parser.parse(row[4])
```

It will readily give you datetime from the Python's builtin datetime module, which can be used for further calculations.

Depending on your problem, timezone may be needed. Read http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html for details.